# Combine strings from multiple rows and join onto another table

Tags: sql

I deleted my other post for the same question and reposting a new one as I feel the other question is confusing. Please pardon me for the duplicate. Hoping this would get some traction

Here is my table A

```
Id   Name
1    Name1
1    Name2
2    Name3
2    Name4
2    Name5

Table B:
Id FileName
1  file1
2  File2
```

I need the output combined with table B as

```
 Id FileName Name
 1  file1    Name1,Name2
 2  file2    Name3,Name4,Name5
```

I tried couple of approaches with COALESE , they work stand-alone, but only when I input Id=<>.

How do I do this combined with two tables?

Please let me know if I can explain more. And I apologize for my last post.

Comment: Depends on RDBMS you're using.

Comment: @Oleg: I have sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Id, FileName,
(SELECT Name+',' FROM A WHERE A.Id = B.Id FOR XML PATH('')) Name
FROM B
```

There is on your responsibility to strip the last comma 8-)

Hint:

```
SELECT Id, FileName,
STUFF((SELECT ','+Name FROM @A a WHERE A.Id = B.Id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') Name
FROM @B b
```

Comment: Thanks very much Oleg. This helped. Looks like I have a long way to go in learning SQL.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
SELECT a.id, b.FileName, 
  REPLACE(
    (SELECT distinct Name AS [data()] 
     FROM TableA a2 
     WHERE a.id=a2.id 
     ORDER BY a2.Name FOR XML PATH('')),
     ' ', ', ')
FROM TableB b inner join TableA a on a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id, b.FileName;
```

Comment: Why do you need the join and groupings here?